# Verror .. rendering dust template: Failed to lookup view in directory

Tags: dust.js, kraken.js

I'm trying to follow a tutorial building a node.js webshop and bumped in to this error which I can't seem to figure out or find a solution for online.

when running `npm start` and going to the page `localhost:8000/admin/products` I get this error:

> **VError: Problem rendering dust template "/Users/Maiteh/nodeshop/public/templates/admin/products.dust": Failed to lookup view "layout/master.dust" in directory "/Users/Maiteh/nodeshop/public/templates"**
>
> at Stub.callback (/Users/Maiteh/nodeshop/node_modules/makara/node_modules/adaro/lib/engine.js:160:30)
>      at Stub.flush (/Users/Maiteh/nodeshop/node_modules/makara/node_modules/adaro/node_modules/dustjs-linkedin/lib/dust.js:559:14)
>      at Chunk.setError (/Users/Maiteh/nodeshop/node_modules/makara/node_modules/adaro/node_modules/dustjs-linkedin/lib/dust.js:1046:15)
>      at done (/Users/Maiteh/nodeshop/node_modules/makara/node_modules/adaro/node_modules/dustjs-linkedin/lib/dust.js:164:28)
>      at /Users/Maiteh/nodeshop/node_modules/dust-makara-helpers/node_modules/iferr/index.js:11:16
>      at read (/Users/Maiteh/nodeshop/node_modules/makara/node_modules/adaro/lib/engine.js:85:28)
>      at /Users/Maiteh/nodeshop/node_modules/makara/node_modules/adaro/lib/engine.js:64:21
>      at /Users/Maiteh/nodeshop/node_modules/makara/node_modules/engine-munger/index.js:101:17
>      at iterate (/Users/Maiteh/nodeshop/node_modules/makara/node_modules/engine-munger/node_modules/permutron/index.js:91:20)
>      at iterate (/Users/Maiteh/nodeshop/node_modules/makara/node_modules/engine-munger/node_modules/permutron/index.js:91:20)

while the file is clearly at that location. My folder structure looks like this:

- NodeShop

  - controllers

    - admin
    - index.js
    - index.js
    - overons.js
  - models

    - index.js
    - overons.js
    - product.js
  - public

    - templates
    - admin

      - products.dust
    - errors...
    - layouts

      - master.dust
    - index.dust
    - overons.dust

And other folders buth that would make it a very long list.

The dust template products.dust looks like this:

```
{>"layout/master" /}
{<title}
  {title}
{/title}
{<body}
  <p>Products</p>
{/body}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a stupid typo I've spend the last couple of hours looking over

{>"layout/master" /}

should have been

{>"layout**s**/master" /}